# undefined method `count=' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added an if statement to see if teacher count goes up because this is classroom_show and it automatically creates a notification if the page is refreshed or redirect to. I thought the count could ensure that a new entry is being saved

Classroom Controller (where the action is being carried out)

```
@classroom_teacher = ClassroomTeacher.new

if @classroom_teacher.save && @classroom.teachers.count +=1
  @classroom.teachers.each do |teacher|
    create_teacher_notification @classroom, teacher
  end
end
```

When I try to go to the page, it gives me an error.

> NoMethodError undefined method `count=' for
>
> Did you mean? count

Is there a better way to make sure that the Classroom Teacher has actually been created? I don't want it to be unique because teachers can be readded to a classroom. I've tried a few things.

```
@classroom_teacher = ClassroomTeacher.build
```

and

```
@classroom_teacher = ClassroomTeacher.create
```

don't work because build and create aren't defined for them here, but they do save successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an association whereby a Classroom has_many :teachers -- is that the case?

If so, I would:

```
@classroom.teachers.new

if @classroom.save
  @classroom.teachers.each do |teacher|
    create_teacher_notification @classroom, teacher
  end
end
```

The save will return false if the new association does not save.

Answer (score 1):

> NoMethodError undefined method `count=' for

The reason for the above error is:

You are trying to call `count=` method on `@classroom.teachers` which will return `ActiveRecord` collection

```
@classroom.teachers.count += 1 # is actually short hand for
@classroom.teachers.count = @classroom.teachers.count + 1
```

What you are trying to achieve can be done by changing this

```
count = @classroom.teachers.count # Save the teachers count in a variable
# Compare the count after save with the previous count
if @classroom_teacher.save && @classroom.teachers.count == count + 1 
  @classroom.teachers.each do |teacher|
    create_teacher_notification @classroom, teacher
  end
end
```

Comment: This works (thanks), but now notifications aren't being created. I used the count to see if a new teacher was being added, but it doesn't seem to count them as new teachers. (no error message to show)

Comment: The reason might be `@classroom_teacher = ClassroomTeacher.new` you are not passing `teacher_id` how come it will increase count of `@classroom.teachers`

Comment: Wouldn't it increase because a ClassroomTeacher, if saved, will have a teacher_id and be recognized as a Classroom.teacher? (I'm still adjusting to rails associations)

Comment: It will increase count of `ClassroomTeacher` but not `@classroom.teachers` as the second thing will fire a query on that table with condition `classroom_id = @classroom.id`

Comment: And Important thing is as pointed out by @David You don't actually need to check this as `@classroom_teacher.save` will return `false` if the record is unable to save

Comment: This issue is that this is in the classroom show method (because that's where teachers are added), and if you ever go to a classroom, a notification is created for teachers whether they're new or already in the classroom. Edit: Just saw his answer, tried it, but it changes lots of my routes.